# Bootstrap Modal window doesn't close even using the data-dismiss tag

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using `bootstrap` to design my page. However, I got an issue when trying to close the modal. It simply doesn't close. Normally the tag `data-dismiss="modal"` should do the work according to the tutorial. So, what's the problem here?

Here is the code for the modal:

```
<!--Dialog referred as by it id -->
<div class="modal fade" id="contact" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;
</button>
<h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<a class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
</div>
</div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->      


<script src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">   

</script>
<script src = "js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/basic.js"></script>
```

Comment: do both close buttons are not working?? i mean one in '<button>' and one in `<a>`??

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code, working fine in my side.

Demo.
http://jsfiddle.net/68e4y/

```
 <!--Dialog referred as by it id -->
<div class="modal fade" id="contact" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;
</button>
<h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<a class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
</div>
</div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->      


<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#contact">
  Launch demo modal
</button>
```

Comment: I tried it with your jsfiddle and it works properly but it's not working with wamp. I still don't understand